# Process is killed suddenly without any debugging message in VS2010

Tags: c#, wcf, process, kill

I am using c# and VS2010.
My program is working client, server and agent.
Each programs are communicated with WCF.

But only agent is killed suddenly. and Server recives agent's fault event.
Generally, if exception is occured in vs 2010, vs2010 is breaked a line that occured a exception
But agent is not stopped. just killed.
It seem to be like pressing "Shift + F5" in VS2010.

So i can't know reason that killed.
Besides, it is occured after 3 - 4 days.

Agent is working with 32 instances.
each instances have 4 threads.

I checked memory leak. but no problem.

So, i want to know debugging skills in this situation.

Please help me.

thanks.

Comment: Turn on WCF tracing on the agent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx Than check failure reason in svctraceviewer.exe

Answer (score 0):

Capture a crash dump and analyze it. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919789/